# What's this mean in a sh script?

Tags: bash

I intend to enter the hive shell(as below) in a sh script and do some HQL request.

```
$ hive
Hive history file=/tmp/admin/hive_job_log_admin_201309110939_570764_8012_1eecdf83_1dd4da6d.txt
hive>
```

Then I got a script which could just work the way I want. The code snippet of sh script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#HQL
/home/hive/hive/bin/hive -u root -p root <<EOF
show tables;
EOF
```

But I don't know what exactly does `<<EOF` and the last `EOF` mean. Could anyone just give me a specific explanation on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is called "here document" (also here-document, heredoc, hereis, here-string or here-script) syntax.

```
<<EOF
show tables;
EOF
```

Yields the text:

```
show tables;
```

For more information see the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/heredoc/info) for [heredoc](/questions/tagged/heredoc).

Answer (score 0):

EOF is just a common heredoc delineator it can be anything not just EOF it can be MyEOF ect. If you declare it like MyEOF then it will use the string MyEOF as a standard input and you can specify $MyEOF as variables which later you can use its contents as stdin. As Johnsyweb mentioned  this is called a herestring, as it uses a short string in contrast to a whole block, as in a heredoc.